# wxpython: Hide one of splitterWindow panels

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, show-hide

I have a frame containing wx.SplitterWindow with two panels as its children. I want to hide one of the panel with a button(show/hide button) click i.e, First panel should hide and the second panel should occupy the whole frame with the sash gone. Clicking the button again should show the hidden panel, and the sash back in place. Is this possible?

I have searched the documentation, and there seems to be no specific method to do this? How can this be achieved.

```
import wx
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="test", size=(800,600))

        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panelOne = wx.Panel(self.splitter,1)
        self.panelTwo = wx.Panel(self.splitter,1)
        self.panelOne.SetBackgroundColour('sky blue')
        self.panelTwo.SetBackgroundColour('pink')
        self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panelOne, self.panelTwo)
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        self.buttonpanel = wx.Panel(self, 1)
        self.buttonpanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.mybutton = wx.Button(self.buttonpanel,label = "Hide")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_hide, self.mybutton)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.splitter, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonpanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def show_hide(self, event):
        label = self.mybutton.GetLabel()
        if label == "Hide":
            ### How to Hide panelOne ??
            self.mybutton.SetLabel("Show")
        if label == "Show":
            ### How to Show panelOne ??
            self.mybutton.SetLabel("Hide")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/SplitterWindow.html#SplitterWindow.Unsplit) for a few seconds, I noticed the `Unsplit` method. You can use that to take out panelOne. Then when you want to Show it again, you just split the `SplitterWindow` again:

```
import wx
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="test", size=(800,600))

        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panelOne = wx.Panel(self.splitter,1)
        self.panelTwo = wx.Panel(self.splitter,1)
        self.panelOne.SetBackgroundColour('sky blue')
        self.panelTwo.SetBackgroundColour('pink')
        self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panelOne, self.panelTwo)
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        self.buttonpanel = wx.Panel(self, 1)
        self.buttonpanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.mybutton = wx.Button(self.buttonpanel,label = "Hide")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_hide, self.mybutton)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.splitter, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonpanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def show_hide(self, event):
        label = self.mybutton.GetLabel()
        if label == "Hide":
            ### How to Hide panelOne ??
            self.mybutton.SetLabel("Show")
            self.splitter.Unsplit(self.panelOne)
        if label == "Show":
            ### How to Show panelOne ??
            self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panelOne, self.panelTwo)
            self.mybutton.SetLabel("Hide")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: You had left off the call to `MainLoop` at the end of the code. This made your example un-runnable.